# tool or method to detect tcl syntax errors

Tags: tcl, syntax-error

If my tcl script contains any syntax errors, the CGI errors are shown in the browser most of the times but this doesn't happen every time.

Is there a way or some open source tool i can use to detect the tcl syntax errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3162) for Tcl static analysis tools lists a number of which I have used 'frink' successfully in the past. Nagelfar is also relatively up to date and I've heard good things about it.

Comment: @user856753, there are two other things to note: 1) an editor which is able to jump between matching parens/braces/brackets (any "real" one) can cheaply help to locate not properly closed "blocks" such as `{...}` and `[...]`; 2) [unit testing](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tcltest).